# Extension of Scalars is a pseudofunctor

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, natural-transformations

Let $\boldsymbol{Ring}$ denote the category of commutative rings with unity (not necessarily different from $0$), and morphisms preserving unity.

I have been wondering if the assignment

$A\in\boldsymbol{Ring}\to A\boldsymbol{mod}$

$(f:A\to B)\to(f^e:=\_\otimes_Af^*B:A\boldsymbol{mod}\to B\boldsymbol{mod})$

is a [pseudofunctor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pseudofunctor) from 1-category $A\boldsymbol{mod}$ to the 2-category $\boldsymbol{Cat}$?

(Here $f^*B$ is $B$ viewed as an $A$ module via the ring map $f$, so $f^e$ is the scalar extension functor along the map $f$.)

So far I am stuck at finding , for $f:A\to B,\,g:B\to C$ ring morphisms and $N\in A\boldsymbol{mod}$, a $C\boldsymbol{mod}$ isomorphisms

$\eta_N:g^e(f^eN)=(N\otimes_Af^*B)\otimes_Bg^*C\to (g\circ f)^eN=N\otimes_A(g\circ f)^*C$

natural in $N$.
My guess is that, on pure tensors, the map should send

$n\otimes f^*b\otimes g^*c=n\otimes f^*1\otimes g^*g(b)c\to n\otimes(g\circ f)^*g(b)c$, but I don't quite know how to prove it is welldefined.

My question is: can this map be welldefined? Is this assignment a pseudofunctor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently, it follows from general nonsense:
Notice that, for every ring morphism $f$, $f^e$ is left adjoint to the scalar restriction functor $f^*$. Now the assignment from $\boldsymbol{Ring}^{op}\to \boldsymbol{Cat}$, on objects
$$A\to A\boldsymbol{mod},$$
on morphisms
$$(f^{op}:A\to B)\to(f^*:A\boldsymbol{mod}\to B\boldsymbol{mod})$$
is a pseudofunctor, and thus gives rise to a [Grothendieck fibration](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+fibration) $p:E\to \boldsymbol{Rings}$. Now, since each $f^*$ has the left adjoint $f^e$, this fibration is also an opfibration (see nlab). So the assignment described in the original post must also be a pseudofunctor. Still it would be interesting to actually see the natural isomorphism worked out.

I guess it always helps to know more category theory :)

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need (op)fibrations to justify that taking adjoints gives you another pseudofunctor : you can just use general facts about adjunctions, namely the fact that adjunctions compose and that any two left adjoints to the same functor are canonically isomorphic.

Comment: Yes, that seems more reasonable, thank you for pointing that out. I don't have much experience with working with adjoint functors (even the definition of it has not quite settled down in my mind), but I'm trying my best!